# Why am I not able to input anything?

Tags: c++, arrays, input

I think I've written correct code but I am not able to input anything. Please help me.

Question - https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/25/A

My code-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n,count(0);
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    for(int i=2; i<n; ++i){
        if(arr[i]-arr[i-1] != arr[i-1]-arr[i-2]){
            ++count;
        }
    }
    cout<<count<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Note:** `n` is uninitialized here, use of `arr[n]` is dangerous and would cause UB. Also, variable-length arrays (VLAs) are not a part of the C++ standard.

Comment: Exactly how many numbers do you think this code will input?

Comment: Use `std::vector` when you need to store values but the quantity is not known at compile time.  Use arrays when the capacity is known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably undefined behavior from your `int n` variable being uninitialized. Initializing `n` to an explicit value allows for input as intended.

Comment: "_It's probably undefined behavior_" It is not only probable. It **is** due to undefined behavior. Simply reading uninitialized variables invokes undefined behavior, according to the standard.